# Graph API - messages - invalid Json produced by API for eventMessageRequest

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

See attached screenshot, when processing the messages in a user's folder, when the message is an "eventMessageRequest" then the json is invalid: it contains the "type" key twice and the Json parsers can't deal with it.

[screenshot of original json received from MS Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5zlw.png)

abbreviated json: note the "type" key used twice:

```
[
  {
    "type": "#microsoft.graph.eventMessageRequest",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-07-01T18:21:32Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-07-01T18:21:33Z",
    "categories": [
    ],
    "receivedDateTime": "2020-07-01T18:21:33Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2020-07-01T18:21:29Z",
    "hasAttachments": true,
    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
    "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "isRead": true,
    "isDraft": false,
    "inferenceClassification": "focused",
    "meetingMessageType": "meetingRequest",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "isOutOfDate": false,
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isDelegated": false,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "allowNewTimeProposals": null,
    "meetingRequestType": "informationalUpdate"
  }
]
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?more_on=xron.net). People here regard that as evil.

Comment: understood - posted updated with json text